# Definite integral of recursive functions

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Let $F_0(x)=x, F_1(x)=4x(1-x), F_{n+1}(x)=F_1(F_n(x))$. Prove that for $n\in\mathbb{Z_0}^+$:
$\int^1_0 F_n(x)\,dx = \frac{2^{2n-1}}{2^{2n}-1}$

Here is progress that I have:
I used the substitution $x=\sin^2\theta$. So $F_1(x)=4\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta=\sin^22\theta$. By an induction argument, we can get $F_n(x)=\sin^22^n\theta$. Now the integral becomes $\int^1_0 2\sin^22^n\theta\sin\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta=\int^1_0 \sin^22^n\theta\sin 2\theta\,d\theta$. How do I evaluate this? I tried integration by parts but it got a little messy, but I'm not sure if it will work out eventually though.

Comment: The following expansion may help you: $$ \sin^2 \alpha \sin \beta = \frac{1}{2}\sin\beta + \frac{1}{4}\sin(2\alpha-\beta) - \frac{1}{4}\sin(2\alpha+\beta). $$

Comment: you can obtain that by  $ \ sin^2 a \ sin b =   \frac  { 1}  {2 }  (1-\cos 2 a) sin\ b$   and $ \ cos 2 a  \sin  b =  \frac {1} {2 }  (\sin (2 a+b) -\sin (2 a-b)).$